# Error regarding function-definition, but it's already been defined

Tags: c++

First and foremost, I'm really struggling with C++ and I'm having trouble grasping some things. A lot of my current work is things I've found online and tried to shape to fit my program. That being said, I'm a student so I'm trying to learn and not just get answers. I'm also using that as forewarning because my code is probably riddled with errors and things that don't make sense. Any pointers on other aspects would be greatly appreciated (which I haven't been able to trial-and-error test yet due to the listed problem). It's obviously still a WIP.

Anyway, my problem is that I'm currently getting an error on line 102 (void sort) saying, "a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token" but I've already defined it at the beginning of my program before main(). I changed the order around a bit so now it's my sort function causing me grief whereas before it was the search function giving problems.

I'm going to include the entirety of the code because as I said, the position things were in seemed to have an effect.

```
//Write a program that store names to an array. 
//The program ends when “quit” is entered.
//The program includes a menu having these choices : 
//getNames, sortNames

, displayNames, findName, removeName.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getName (string nameEntries[]);
void remove (string nameEntries[]);
void sort (string nameEntries[]);
void search (string nameEntries[]);
void display (string nameEntries[]);

int main()
{
    const int MAXSTRINGS = 20; //Max number of names to be entered
    string nameEntries[MAXSTRINGS];
    string input;

    cout << "Please enter an option from the following: " << endl;
    cout << "'Get' - Allows entry of names to list (Max 20)." << endl;
    cout << "'Display' - Shows current entries of list." << endl;
    cout << "'Sort' - Alphabetizes entries of list." << endl;
    cout << "'Search' - Finds name on current list." << endl;
    cout << "'Remove' - Removes an entry from the list." << endl;
    cout << "'Quit' - Ends the program." << endl;

    cin >> input;

    if (input == "Get" || "get" ) //Runs function to add names to list.
        {
            getName(nameEntries);
        }
    else if (input == "Remove" || "remove" ) //Runs function to remove specified name from list.
        {
            remove(nameEntries);
        }
    else if (input == "Sort" || "sort" ) //Runs function to sort list alphabetically.
        {
            sort(nameEntries);
        }
    else if (input == "Search" || "search" ) //Runs function to search list for a specified name.
        {
            search(nameEntries);
        }
    else if (input ==  "Display" || "display" ) //Runs function to display current entries.
        {
            display(nameEntries);
        }
    else if (input == "Quit" || "quit" ) //Exits program.
        {
            return 0;
        }
    while  (input != "Display" && "display" && "Find" && "find" && "Remove" && "remove" && "Sort" && "sort" && "Get" && "get" && "Quit" && "quit")
        {
            cout << "Please enter a menu option: ";
            cin >> input;
        }
}

//Allows continued entry of names to array
void getName(string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < MAXSTRINGS; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name for storage or 'Menu' for more options: ";
        cin >> nameEntries[MAXSTRINGS];
        if (cin == "Menu" || "menu")
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    return;
}

//Remove specified previously entered name from array       
void remove (string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
{
    string Empty;
    string nameRemove;
    cout << "Please enter the name to remove from the list: ";
    cin >> nameRemove;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXSTRINGS; i++)
    {
        if(nameEntries[i] == nameRemove)
        {
             nameEntries[i] = Empty;             //previous constant to represent your "empty" cell
        }
        else if(i == MAXSTRINGS - 1)    //on last loop, tell the user you could not find it.
        {
            cout << "Could not find that name to remove.";
        }
    return; 
}

//Alphabetize inputted names in array 
void sort (string nameEntries[], int size)
{
    bool flag;
    do
    {
        flag = 0;
        for (int count = 0; count < size-1; count++)
        {
            if (nameEntries[count] > nameEntries[count+1])
            {
                nameEntries[count].swap(nameEntries[count+1]);
                flag =1;
            }
        }
    }
    while (flag==1);
    return;
}

//Search array for desired name entry
void search (string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
{
    string name;

    cout<<"Please enter a name to search for or Quit to return:";
    cin >> name;
    if (name == "Quit" || "quit") return;

    int first = 0;
    int last = size - 1;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && first <= last)
    {
        int middle = (first + last) / 2;
        if (nameEntries[middle] == name)
        {
            found = true;
            cout<<array[middle]<<" is on the list."<<endl;
        }
        else if (array[middle] > name)
            last = middle - 1;
        else
            first = middle + 1;
        }

    return;
}

//Show current entries in array
void display (string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
{
    cout << nameEntries[MAXSTRINGS];
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop in `remove` doesn't have a closing brace

Comment: Quick example: You tell the compiler that `void getName (string nameEntries[]);` exists, but what you provide later is `void getName(string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)` They don't match.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed both of these among a couple of other things.

Comment: Beginner C++ student here as well, but one possible issue is with adding and deleting. If you delete a name, you'll have a gap in your array...but to then add another name into that gap, you will have to retype out all the stored names. I think that, when you delete, you should move everything up the array and then provide the option when adding to add names from the first empty string. Hope this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

2 problems with your code:

```
void remove (string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
{
    string Empty;
    string nameRemove;
    cout << "Please enter the name to remove from the list: ";
    cin >> nameRemove;

    for(int i = 0; i < MAXSTRINGS; i++)
    {
        if(nameEntries[i] == nameRemove)
        {
             nameEntries[i] = Empty;             //previous constant to represent your "empty" cell
        }
        else if(i == MAXSTRINGS - 1)    //on last loop, tell the user you could not find it.
        {
            cout << "Could not find that name to remove.";
        }
    // Missing a closing curly brace here <---
    return; 
}
```

**Firstly**, your for-loop is missing a closing curly brace. This means that the closing curly brace of the function `remove()` is viewed by the compiler as the closing curly brace of the for-loop. Hence, the compiler sees that you are trying to define the next function, which is `sort()`, inside the `remove()`function, as the closing curly brace of the `remove()` function has not been reached yet. This is not allowed in c++, so the compiler spits out the error:

> a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

**Secondly**,

```
void getName (string nameEntries[]);
```

This is the function declaration at the start of the program.

```
void getName(string nameEntries[], const int MAXSTRINGS)
```

This is the function header when the function is being defined later in the program.

The compiler sees 2 different functions here. Even though they have the same name, the compiler can differentiate these 2 functions by their different arguments. The first one only has a single argument, and the second one has 2 arguments. However, the first function is never defined, and the second function is never declared above `int main()`. So, if you try to implelemt the first function, you will get an error saying that the function is undefined (error message won't say that exactly), and if you try to implement the second function, you will get an error that the functiin was not declared jn this scope. This problem is in all your functions.

To fix this issue, add/remove the required/unrequired parameters so that the function declaration and function definition match.